# OpenGL rectangle inexplicably takes up entire window

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, sdl-2

So I am using GLEW & SDL2. At the moment I'm having trouble with drawing a simple rectangle.
I've done this before and got it to work no problem. (I have checked my old code, but could not find any signifigant differences)

Here's what the output should look like, aside from a different background color.
[image]

However, this is what the output looks like:
[image]

When I check the output with Renderdoc, all the values seem to be as they should be, but for some reason the output rectangle is signifigantly larger than the viewport. (Assuming the white border in the output window represents the viewport.)
[image]

I've googled around a bit, but could not find any solution to this issue. I'm figuring I'm just missing a single function call somewhere which is causing the program to output things in a weird way.

Here's the relevant code

**game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

void Game::Game::main_loop()
{
    //Placeholder setup;
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = { 
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0 
    };  

    unsigned int vertex_array, vertex_buffer, element_buffer;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &element_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, element_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    Asset::Loader l;
    auto s = l.load_shader("res/GUI/Shaders/Textured_quad.vert", "res/GUI/Shaders/Textured_quad.frag");

    keep_going = true;
    while(keep_going)
    {
        handle_events();
        renderer.clear();

        s->use(); //Just calls 'glUseProgram' on the shader inside this object
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        renderer.show();
    }
}

void Game::Game::handle_events()
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        case SDL_QUIT:
            keep_going = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Renderer.cpp**

```
#include "Renderer.h"

Game::Graphics::Renderer::Renderer()
{
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 5);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 5);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 5);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "GUI", 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED_DISPLAY(1),
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED_DISPLAY(1),
        640,
        480,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
    );

    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(
        window
    );

    if(!window)
    {
        std::cerr << "Window Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if(!context)
    {
        std::cerr << "GL Context Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    glewInit();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}

Game::Graphics::Renderer::~Renderer()
{
    SDL_HideWindow(window);
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}

void Game::Graphics::Renderer::clear()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void Game::Graphics::Renderer::show()
{
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
```

**Shader**

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(a_pos, 0.0f);
}

//fragment
#version 330 core

out vec4 o_color;

void main()
{
    o_color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Post the shader code too.

Comment: Updated with shader code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> gl_Position = vec4(a_pos, 0.0f);
> ```

The X/Y/Z coordinates in gl_Position get divided by the W coordinate to get the screen coordinates. You are setting the W coordinate to 0, which means the X and Y coordinates become infinity and -infinity (1/0 and -1/0) and the Z coordinate becomes NaN.

Change it to:

> ```
>                           vvvv
> gl_Position = vec4(a_pos, 1.0f);
> ```

Comment: This ended up being the culprit. I overlooked that single digit. Thanks.

Comment: " You are setting the W coordinate to 0, which means the X and Y coordinates become infinity and -infinity" That is actually _not_ the case. The perspective divide comes _after_ the clipping, and a point `(x,y,z,0)` will fulfill the clip condition `-w <= x,y,z <= w` only for the very specific case of `x=y=z=0` (which is a very odd special case which never appears if a proper projection matrix is used), but for all other points, the processing is actually well-defined.

Comment: @derhass hmm, then why does it render anything at all?

Comment: because the primitive might still intersect with the view volume. If you have `w=0`, points are basically at infiniy, but if you have a primitive with for examples the vertices  `(-1,-1,-1,0)` to `(1,1,1,0)`, it will go right through the view volume, and be clipped ot a finite polygon (attribute interpolation is still screwed if you use w=0, but the basic rasterization will work)